# Adding nodes automatically without clicking the mouse

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, digitizing, polyline-creation, nodes

Is there a way in QGIS (or maybe in another GIS (ArcMap, for example))) to automatically create nodes at a given interval when digitizing a raster?

For example, I decided to create a Polyline object. I created a starting point and then just move the mouse in the desired direction. At this time QGIS is listening for the line length. If the length of the drawn line reaches 10m, a node is created automatically in the place of the mouse pointer. At the end of procedure, as usual, right click to complete the polyline.

[image: Example]

I attach this pseudocode:

```
my_length = 10
start_point = create_point_on_left_click_event(get_coords_from_mouse_pointer())
while !right_click_event:
    #line_length_listetning...
    on_event(line_length == my_length):
        node = create_node(get_coords_from_mouse_pointer())
        new_start_point = node

end_point = create_point_on_right_click_event(get_coords_from_mouse_pointer())    
#completion Polyline
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with QGIS 3.20, there is the [new Streaming digitizing mode](https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-streaming-digitizing-mode). When digitizing a line or polygon, simply activate it by pressing the `R` key (or click the icon). When you now move the mouse over the map canvas, QGIS adds vertices without clicking.

You can always activate/deactivate streaming digizing mode and change betwen it and "normal" mode by pressing `R` key. End drawing your line or polygon as usual by right-clicking.

*Drawing a polygon with activated Streaming digitizing mode: vertices are created automatically without clicking. This allows to draw smooth curves manually be moving the mouse over the map canvas:*
[image]